# Create column in TEasyListView

Tags: delphi, listview

I use TEasyListView from [mustangpeak.net](http://mustangpeak.net). I'd like to create a combobox in a column. I can't find any sample to do this from the component demo. If I use TListView, I could follow a trick from http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=801 but I need to use TEasyListView. Please, give me some guides.

Comment: tried to follow the link and it seems to me that the project is now defunct. why do you still need to use it?

Comment: I use this component because of its performance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232623/how-to-fast-read-and-write-in-listview-in-delphi). If I decide to use TListView, it seems I have to spend more time to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I would guess TEasyListView is a descendant of TListView since pretty much everyone creates new components based on lower level components.  Try checking back into the components and you will more then likely find a way to use the "trick" you named above.

Comment: Maybe you know the famous VirtualShellTools. TEasyListView is the part of VST. http://code.google.com/p/mustangpeakeasylistview/

Comment: Nope, never heard of em.  But someplace in there it is either going to be a wrapper around a win32 call OR you are going to be able to get to the canvas.