# The loading pictures and data into Delphi XE6 Listview through the Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, listview, delphi-xe6

Frankly, despite of my large investigation on this issue I have few difficulties in understanding some information. By aggregating all the data about Thread that I searched and found there are a lot of weird things turned out. I would like to know your opinions about the way how the scenario should be set and from where to begin?! 
Not far, I would like to start by giving an example of the implementation on ANDROID….
Certainly, I want to ask about the listing/sorting information that occurs - for example when we search “Game” by typing in a search engine.
Taking an instance from Delphi…
As I understood by sorting process, first of all the data is loading to the Listview by parsing, them the pictures are loading through the Listview Items.
The operations are taking place on this process are fallowing by Threads.
During the loading the data at the same time the pictures are uploading separately for the Item one-by-one.
There is occurring no any problem, delaying in load process or confusion/freezing if we move the list upward-downward while loading process.
What do I need in order to achieve such kind of operation ?!
How the scenario is supposed to be set ?!
Are the uploading pictures placing initially into the phone memory rather than required Items ?!
Or, they are placing directly into Items ?!

Comment: Don't mix GUI and business logic. Use `TListView` in virtual mode. See [How to fast read and write in listview in delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4232623/576719).

Comment: What do you want to mean by pointing Business or why do you associating it with business ?!

Comment: Business logic is a common description of the logic that makes your program doing something useful. A good structured of program don't rely on user interface components for the business logic. By using the TListView in virtual mode, you can keep the business logic separated from the GUI. In your case here is means that you can make your own structure how to handle the loading in the best way, and just let the GUI be informed of any added items. This will trigger an event to present data, where you just fill in the data from your own structure.

Comment: If you'd like help, the very first thing you should start with is breaking that wall of text you've posted into readable paragraphs. StackOverflow accepts them, and you can see the effect in real time (WYSIWYG) format right below the area where you're typing your question. Paragraphs make text much easier to read and comprehend, which makes it much easier to understand your question and improves the chances you'll get an answer.